# Unhandled exception at 0x7584c54f (KernelBase.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, exception

I am facing this issue when i tried to Debug the project.

Unhandled exception at 0x7584c54f (KernelBase.dll) in xyz.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0126f258..

I have tried all the possibilities found on other threads but still unable to run the project.

The call stack is as follows:

> KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x58 bytes
>       libEGL.dll!68658ccf()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for    libEGL.dll] 
>       libEGL.dll!6864b083()
>       libEGL.dll!68657dae()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)". It worked for me.

Property Pages => Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Code Generation => Runtime Library